# How to change text format of QDoubleSpinbox?

Tags: python, qt, pyside, qtgui, qspinbox

I want to enter temperature in my dialog in this format 12°15°

For this i took QDoubleSpinBox widget but wasn't able to set its text like above.

I tried following:

```
degree_sign= u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'
temperature = QDOubleSpinBox()
temperature.setSuffix(degree_sign)
```

and got 12.15°

I think valueFromText() and textFromValue() can help but don't know how to use them.

How to set QDoubleSpinBox text(or value) format like 12°15°?

Comment: Wait a second, what is `12°15°`? Is that a real temperature format? And if so, why don't you inherit from QDS?

Comment: @lpapp 12°15° means 12.15 degree . I want temperature in this format. Please provide an example of QDS or some link.

Comment: So why not 12.15°? Is this defined by some local standard?

Comment: @lpapp yes its local standard

Answer (score 0):

One way is inherit from QDoubleSpinBox and override the respective methods as follows in this **pseudo** code:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QApplication>

class MySpinBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        explicit MySpinBox(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDoubleSpinBox(parent) {}
    double valueFromText(const QString & text) const
    {
        QString valueText = text;
        valueText.chop(1);
        valueText.replace("°", ".");
        return valueText.toFloat();
    }

    QString textFromValue(double value) const
    {
        QString valueText = QString::number(value);
        valueText.replace(".", "°");
        valueText.append(".");
        return valueText;
    }
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication application(argc, argv);
    MySpinBox mySpinBox;
    mySpinBox.show();
    return application.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT += widgets
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```

Disclaimer: even though it looks like a compiling code, it does *not* work, but shows the concept.

Comment: I have converted all code to python except this line `QString valueText = QString::number(value);`  I tried to convert this as `valueText = str(value)` but it gives error

Comment: I converted code to pyqt but qdoublespinbox shows `0.`

Comment: Yes, that is why I marked the answer as pseudo code. The concept is there and you need to fine tune it.

Comment: Yes i modified it to get 0°00° `def valueFromText(self, text):
        valueText = QString()
        valueText = text
        valueText.chop(1)
        valueText.replace(degree_sign,".")
        return t.toFloat()

    def textFromValue(self, value):
        valueText = QString.number(value, format='f', precision=2)
        valueText.replace(".", degree_sign)
        valueText.append(degree_sign)
        return valueText`

On clicking up it only increments first value. I am not able to modify second value. Give some hint. Also tell where to learn overriding Qt widgets

Comment: @Patrick: please [read the documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qdoublespinbox.html#singleStep-prop). The default step is 1.0, that is why. You need to change that.

Comment: agreed default value is 1.0 still i can edit fraction part in QDoubleSpinBox but was not able to edit fraction part in MySpinBox